# I can't even select the options on RetroArch (Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: 14.10, emulation

I installed RetroArch emulator on Ubuntu 14.10, there were no problems with the installation itself but when I open the software I can't "properly" select any options from the main menu because it seems to be accelerated, e.g. when I click the down arrow once, it jumps six times. With some patience I got to select a core and run a game, but as expected the game was behaving oddly (accelerated and "all blinky").

It looks like some sort of problem with the FPS because it is around 800 and changes a lot.

I think my openGL library and nvidia drivers are at the latest versions.

Any ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting "Limit Maximum Run Speed" to ON (Settings -> General Options).